# Algorithm to convert rendered number back into symbolic form

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, mathematical-programming

If you have a number such as $3.14626437$ and you need to know what symbols create it, as far as I know, there are two tools:

1- [ISC](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard)

2- [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.14626437)

and the answer is $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$

I am wondering what algorithm these websites are using and how much is their complexity?

Comment: What research have you done? If you go to [the Wikipedia page for ISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Symbolic_Calculator), which links to [the Wikipedia page for closed-form expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), which links to [RIES](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html), which describes the algorithm it uses.  Next time, perhaps a bit more sleuthing before asking might be beneficial...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RIES](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html) is another [method for finding closed-form expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression); its web page describes the algorithm it uses.

If you do a Google search for `algorithm for inverse symbolic calculator`, you will find [Wikipedia's page on algorithms for finding integer relations between multiple real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) (as the page describes, you look for an integer relation between $x$, the number you care about, and a list of other standard mathematical constants).